# Are Datalog rules and Datomic rules equivalent

Tags: clojure, datomic, datalog

I have a simple Datalog program I am trying to express in Datomic using Closure. The idea is `assertions` can be selected, and selecting some assertions also selects others. Here is the Datalog program:

```
% Facts
assertion("id1", "1").
assertion("id11", "1.1").
assertion("id2", "2").
assertion("id3", "3").

select_assertion("id1").

% Rules:
selected(Id, Name) :- assertion(Id, Name), select_assertion(Id).

select_assertion(IdChild) :-
  assertion(IdChild, "1.1"),
  assertion(IdParent, "1"),
  select_assertion(IdParent).
```

Running the query:

```
selected(A,B)?
=>
selected(id1, 1).
selected(id11, "1.1").
```

Selecting '1', also selects '1.1'. I've been trying to express this in Datomic but have found it difficult to get the `rules` to look the same as the `facts` such that a query does differentiate them. This is as far as I have got:

```
% ... connection stuff

(def schema [{:db/ident :assertion/name
              :db/valueType :db.type/string
              :db/cardinality :db.cardinality/one
              :db/doc "The name of an assertion"}

             {:db/ident :select_assertion/assertion
              :db/valueType :db.type/ref
              :db/cardinality :db.cardinality/one
              :db/doc "The ID of an assertion to be selected"}
             ])

(def data [
           {:db/id "id-1" :assertion/name "1"}
           {:assertion/name "1.1"}
           {:assertion/name "2"}
           {:assertion/name "3"}
           {:select_assertion/assertion "id-1"}
           ])

(def rules '[
             [(selected ?assertion_name)
              [?a :assertion/name ?assertion_name]
              [_ :select_assertion/assertion ?a]]

             [(select_assertion "1.1")
              [?a :assertion/name "1"]
              [_ :select_assertion/assertion ?a]]])

(def selected '[:find ?c
                :in $ %
                :where
                (selected ?c)])

(defn reload-dbs []
  (d/transact conn {:tx-data schema})
  (d/transact conn {:tx-data data}))

(defn query []
  (d/q selected db rules))
```

How do I make the Datomic query return the same thing without resorting to a disjunction?

Comment: It sounds like you are more interested in logic programming than a database?  If so, you may want:  https://github.com/clojure/core.logic

Comment: Don't you mean Clojure instead of closures? If so, you may want to fix the tags.

Answer (score 1):

While I haven't been able to answer the question of 'are they equivalent', I have been able to get a similar effect after watching https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=bAilFQdaiHk&feature=youtu.be&t=464. It points out that multiple rules with the same name combine with implicit OR. This seems similar to Datalog.

Switching the code to:

```
(def rules '[
             [(selected ?a)
              [?a :assertion/name ?assertion_name]
              [_ :select_assertion/assertion ?a]]
             [(selected ?a)
              [?a  :assertion/name "1.1"]
              [?ap :assertion/name "1"]
              [_ :select_assertion/assertion ?ap]]])

(def selected '[:find ?a ?n
                :in $ %
                :where
                (selected ?a)
                [?a :assertion/name ?n]])
```

Gives the right answer. Here the first `selected` returns the ID of entities that have names, and are also selected. The second `selected` returns the ID of an entity if it has the name "1.1" and there is another entity that has a name "1" and is also selected.

I think my confusion surrounds the idea of `entity`. In Datomic you can have an entity with any combination of attributes. However, in [Datalog](https://x775.net/2019/03/18/Introduction-to-Datalog.html) they have `atoms` whose name is the `predicate`. In Datomic you can get the same affect as these `predicates` by creating a rule that returns the attributes you want.